# Clojure issue, can't convert list of strings to numbers

Tags: clojure, io

For the code below I'm reading input from stdin. Basically it's just some numbers delimited by spaces or line breaks. Specifically I'm trying to complete [this challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-sticks).

My goal is to create a list of numbers (without the first number) from the input. When I run the code below at hackerrank I get a list of a single number: `(5)`

Not sure what's going on, or how to fix. Would anyone know?

```
(map read-string (rest (line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line-seq` gives one string for each line. `read-string` reads from a string, returning the first complete object found. Thus, you only get the first item on the line.

You could either us `clojure.string/split` to break up the string and use `read-string` on each part, or `loop`, accumulating the results of calling `read` on a PushbackReader made from the BufferedReader until you get no more input.

Answer (score 2):

Since your input is

> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains a single integer N.
>
> The next line contains N integers: a0, a1,...aN-1 separated by space...
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> 6
>
> 5 4 4 2 2 8

And you don't need to worry about validation / security, you can just

```
(let [n (read-string (read-line))
      v (read-string (str "[" (read-line) "]"))]
  (assert (== n (count v))) ;if you like
  (comment solution here...))
```

Comment: Although this answer didn't directly answer my question about what was wrong with my code I like the use of read-line which gets rid of the ugly java code.